# Change the color of the selector in Bottom bar

Tags: android, bottombar

I have a BottomBar in my app.
I want to change the color of the selector of its items.
That's when it was clicked on the item to change its color!
By default, colorPrimary has been set to this by default.
What should I do to change its color?

Comment: Which BottomBar ? Do you mean BottomNavigationBar ?

Comment: Not Bottom Navigation !
I used the Bottom Navigation, but I could not work with it and move the fragments
I mean the Bottom Bar

Answer (score 0):

I think that this can help you to change the color

```
// Pass on the activity and color resourse
    Utils.darkenStatusBar(this, R.color.orange);
```

I don't test the code, but maybe if you put this inside of clic you can change it

[Reference](http://www.gadgetsaint.com/tips/change-statusbar-color-android/#.Wos5nqinFhE)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the reference, Untils it's a class, you can check it here,  http://www.gadgetsaint.com/tips/change-statusbar-color-android/#.Wos5nqinFhE